# Synchronous sequelize.sync() or different way?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, sequelize.js, synchronous

I am new to working with Sequelize on my Express-generator based project. I am using Sequelize for my MySQL database and I need to start database before starting to listen for http requests from website. First what I did was:

app.js

```
sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.use('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use('/auth', auth);
    //etc etc etc...
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

But something saying me this is not right style. Is there better way? Or just use synchronous call before running express routes, etc, like this:

```
syncFunctionWhatCallsSequelizeSync();

app.use('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/auth', auth);
//etc etc etc...
```

Comment: Your first example is just fine. If you prefer to make your code look synchronous, you could just use `async/await`.

Comment: But first code is messy and don't follow the "one module do one thing standard"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure routes, middleware etc before sync() given that your server only listens after sync().

```
// Configure routes
// Configure middleware
// Configure etc
models.sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        // Start listening 
    })
    .catch(err => {

    });
```

Comment: where is `models` definitions